# Electric kick drum pedal starts oscillating in such a way that it does not register hits

Tags: electronic-drumset

I am a beginning drummer and have an electric drumkit with a Yamaha kick drum, the one shown below.
For some specific songs where the kick drum is a consistent beat, I cannot seem to produce a consistent sound myself.

The reason for this is hard to explain in text; as I'm rhythmically stepping on the kick drum, the spring causes the foot pedal to start oscillating up and down (like when you twang a plastic ruler). Those oscillations have the same frequency as the kick drum beats. As I kick down on the foot pedal and raise my foot again, the pedal raises with it. However, it bounces back down again due to the force (not my foot) and as the pedal is traveling downwards, my foot kicks on the pedal again. At that point, the pedal has almost hit the foam hit marker, and my foot adds no extra force; no hit or a soft hit can be heard instead of kick.

My apologies for the rather vague explanation. I'm wondering if anyone else recognizes this and has any advice on how to make it stop. It happens in any configuration of my foot to the pedal (ball of foot, heel, full foot, just toes)

[image]

Comment: I have the same "issue" with my [Alesis Nitro Mesh kit which has a legit kickdrum "beater"](https://www.alesis.com/products/view2/nitro-mesh-kit). But I thought it was a "feature" to make it easier to [play doubles](https://youtu.be/3lkZPJES45Q?t=18)... Wondering if this is the same issue?

Comment: @EricSeastrand Perhaps, but my problem is not that the oscillation causes double notes, it's that it causes my hits to not register, because the moment I stamp my foot on the pedal, the pedal is already at its lowest point to the foam because it oscillated there.

Comment: Coming back to this after years, I think the problem was simply that it was a rather cheap kit. I've since went on to a better kit with an actual beater, and this hasn't been an issue anymore. @EricSeastrand The only thing I can think of in your case is that the spring tension on your beater might be a little too high.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The usual fix for that is to adjust the spring tension &/or the beater post length.

As that doesn't appear to have either, then I'd suggest jamming another bit of soft foam in the way, to slow up the oscillation.

Comment: Practical advice, thanks! If I understand correctly: by adding some more foam, the spring won't be forced together as much when I kick down, and so will not push back as hard when I release my foot, making the pedal not oscillate as much.

Comment: If the foam is soft enough, it won't provide sufficient resistance to your playing, just enough to slow up the rebound. I'm sure it will take some fiddling with to get it just right... unless there **is** some kind of tension adjuster in the pedal.

Comment: Will check for any adjustment possibility first. Thanks!

Comment: other possibilities are double kick pedals, or a drum machine.